# How to match every space preceded by at least 6 characters since the last matched space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm copying this question from a recently deleted one that I thought was interesting, but was stumped trying to answer.

### tl;dr:

How to match spaces preceded by at least 6 characters which do not include any matched spaces?

---

I am trying to write this regex to match spaces that have 6 or more characters/non-matched space between them, so that I can use `.split()` to break them into different lines.

Sample:

- Kaiya Devine Rahman
- Zunairah Field Cairns
- Oliwia Ramos Smith
- Donald Ben Ed Jax

What I have so far: `/(?<=.{6,})\s/g`

This doesn't work correctly.  For example, it matches all the spaces in the last name (split result: `['Donald', 'Ben', 'Ed', 'Jax']`). Instead I want the split result to be `['Donald', 'Ben Ed', 'Jax']`. How do you make it so that after the first match (the space after Donald), it starts searching from that index instead?

[image: screenshot of regex and matches]

- https://regex101.com/r/bzyFtQ/2

Comment: Lookbehind is a non-consuming pattern, so you cannot use it here. `\K` is not supported, so you need a matching regex, not  a splitting one. Please provide the pattern requirements.

Comment: From what you said this should also not be selected: `Kayiya~here~Devine Rehman` ?

Comment: You mispelled `Kaiya` (5 chars) as `Kayiya` (6 chars).  In your example, the first space should be matched, yes.  Because it's preceded by at least 6 characters that don't include a matched space.

Comment: In `'Zunairah Field Cairns'` why is the space after `'Field'` matched considering that `'Field'` is five characters and the space before `'Field'` is matched? Same question for the space after `'Ramos'` in `'Oliwia Ramos Smith'`.

Comment: I hadn't noticed those are also incorrect matches.  But the current Best Answer handles them properly (doesn't match them).

Comment: Please correct the question as many members may see it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `(?<=(\S|(?<!\S{6,})\s){6,})\s`

[Test it here at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/D1oswG/1)

Comment: This doesn't match the space between `'Ed'` and `'Jax'` in `'Donald Ben Ed Jax'`.

Comment: @GirkovArpa Why would it?  `'Ed'` is only 2 characters long and you need at least 6 characters to match a space.

Comment: Because it matches the first space in `'Donald Ben Ed Jax'`, leaving `'Ben Ed Jax'` with no matches.  `'Ben Ed'` is 6 characters long so the space after it should be matched.  The goal is to split names into segments 6 characters in length, but only at spaces, not before.

Comment: @GirkovArpa New and improved.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your regex in a linked regex tester? Your lookbehinds are flagged as errors at regex101.com (which suprised me). I don't know Javascript, but I've read that is hasn't always supported lookbehinds, fixed- or variable-length, and even now some browsers don't accept Javascript lookbehinds. Please clarify.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added the link and it tested ok.

Comment: I get "pattern error" at the link (for both lookbehinds). Any idea why, considering it works for you?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The version of the browser maybe?

Comment: Hmm. I recently switched from Chrome to Safari. I'll have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't simple `/(^\w+)\s(.+)\s(\w+)$/` what you really need?
https://regex101.com/r/phAKGH/1

Comment: I apologize but I had to take back your Best Answer because it fails on the following string: `Orange Banana Apple Gooseberry Plum`.  It doesn't break `Banana Apple Gooseberry` at either space.

Comment: I just thought you need simple firs name/middle name/last name cut. But if you really need that 6-characters logic maybe it's enough just to use the regex like /\w{6,}/ and cycling over the string?

Comment: It also splits at the space immediately after `Kaiya` which it shouldn't because it's only 5 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more like:

```js
function separateName(name){
  const a = name.split(/\s+/);
  if(a.length > 3){
    a[1] += ' '+a.splice(2, 1);
  }
  return a;
}
const testArray = ['Kaiya Devine Rahman', 'Zunairah Field Cairns', 'Oliwia Ramos Smith', 'Donald Ben Ed Jax'];
for(let n of testArray){
  console.log(separateName(n));
}
```

Comment: This is a practical workaround but doesn't technically answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the following approach to avoid the use of lookbehinds as I understand they are not supported by all browsers.

If you match the following regex there is a space of interest immediately following each match.

```
/(?:^| ).{6}[^ \n]*(?= )/
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/Uxto8g/5/)

If, for example, the string were:

```
"Now is the time for exceptional  Rubiests to be extra vigilent in the testing phases"
```

there would be 8 matches (note there are two spaces before `'Rubiests'`):

```
"Now is"
" the time"
" for exceptional"
"  Rubiests"
" to be extra
" vigilent"
" in the"
" testing"
```

The first character of each match but the first is a matched space; that is, that space is preceded by at least 6 characters that follow the last matched space or the beginning of the string.

These 8 matches, when concatenated, form the first part of the string. It is therefore easy to compute the index of each matched space.

Comment: I've tried your pattern.  (This is not the main thing, but the last word or group is not selected)  My question is how do you use that regex to separate the string without leaving the spaces in it.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed `"...split()..."`. I was going by the title, which I suggest you change to "How to split a string on every space preceded by at least 6 characters since the last matched space?". You still need to correct "Field" and "Ramos" in your question.